# Loading initial data from csv with migrations in Django 1.10

Tags: django, python-2.7, csv, sqlite

This is what I have after multiple tries.

- My ASCII csv data is located at `/.../myproject/myapp/committees.csv`. It is delimited by `'|'`. There are no quotes around each string, but some fields have quotes (double and single) in them. It has a header.
- My migrations files are at the default `/.../myproject/myapp/migrations/` directory. I've deleted all previous tries at migration files to start over, so it's just got the `__init__.py/c` files.
- My database is the default django sqlite3 one at `/.../myproject/db.sqlite3`.
- My `Committees` model is the exact fields from the csv header, all `models.CharField(max_length = 100)`. It is at the default `/.../myproject/myapp/models.py`. I named the dbtable 'Committees'.

At this point, I can run sqlite3 commandline and see an empty 'Committees' table in my 'main' database. The schema is correct (a bunch of `VARCHAR(100)` fields).

First, I run this in `/.../myproject/`:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp --name load_intial_data
```

I open up `/.../myproject/myapp/migrations/0001_load_intial_data.py` and edit it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10.5 on 2017-01-13 18:00
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
import os

# where is the file
directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
fp = os.path.join(directory, 'commmittees.csv')

# an earlier try with raw SQL
cmd = "BULK INSERT Committees FROM '" + fp + \
      "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = " + \
      "'\r\n', ERRORFILE = 'committees.sql.err.csv', TABLOCK);"

# python with DictReader, which takes the first line/header as keys
def csv2dj_com(apps, schema_editor):
    with open(fp, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = '|')
        for row in reader:
            obj = Committees(row)
            obj.save()
            print('YAYAYAY')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(csv2dj_com),
        #migrations.RunSQL(cmd)
    ]
```

(Note there were two different ways I thought of doing this, but I think the SQL way would not assign the correct fields? Unclear. Went with the RunPython). Running `python manage.py migrate myapp` gives this error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/.../myproject/myapp/commmittees.csv'
```

Now, before, when I was trying to do this without Migrations, I ran into errors where my python files were not on django's path. It was sort of fixed with fiddling around with the code below, which removed errors from my django server, but it never actually added initial data to the database.

```
import sys, os
directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ))) #, '..', 'myproject')
sys.path.append(directory)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()
```

Not exactly sure what to do next. How do you load data from csv to django's model/database?

Comment: Why don't you give it the absolute path just for further debugging? How do you get the `Committees` model btw? Don't import it, do `apps.get_model('app_name.Committees')`

Comment: thanks @schwobaseggl, that fixed it. Because I deleted migrations, it breaks now on 'LookupError: No installed app with label 'myapp'.' I'll start over. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You can also use fixtures to provide initial data for models. Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/